# How can I get all the contact folders along with contact subFolders using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Graph API in my java Application

```
    ContactFolderCollectionPage contactFolderCollectionPage = graphClient.users(email).contactFolders("Contacts").childFolders()
                          .buildRequest().top(maxNumber).count(true).skip(offset).get();
```

With the above api I'm only able to get the folders in the Contacts folder but not all the subFolders and childFolders.

Is there any way to get the whole folder hierarchy (childFolders and grandChild Folders) using graph api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
.Top(999).Expand("childFolders")
```

which should expand 1 level of child folders, if you have any more depth then that you will then need to execute further request on those child folders to get those sub children. The Graph doesn't allow deep traversal so you can't get really deep level hierarchies in one call. You max number variable shouldn't be any large then 1000 which is the maximum page size each supports.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have came to know about expand(). but I actually need to get deep traversal. which might not be possible in graph api.

Comment: just for a quick update, by using the graph beta client we can get all the folders and subFolders (deep traversal). However, using of beta client in production is not recommended.